# custom font can use in interface builder but not able in program

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I am using Roboto in my project. I don't know why the font can use in interface builder but not in program.

Interface builder:

[image: Interface builder]

program:
[image]

plist:

[image]

Comment: Did you add the font info in the plist?

Comment: sure, that is why i can use it in interface builder.

Comment: did you print out all the font names? Like using this code : `for family: String in UIFont.familyNames()
{
     print("\(family)")
     for names: String in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family)
     {
         print("== \(names)")
     }
}`

Use this code anywhere(app delegate is best). And see what is the actual name of the font you want to use. And use that name.

Comment: OH! I cannot find the Roboto.. Do you know how to fix it? Mr. UB

Comment: Try cleaning project, re-opening Xcode. Or re-installing fonts.
One more thing, check in 'build phases'->'Copy bundle resourcs', whether your fonts included or not.